# Why is there a Convert.ToInt32(DateTime) method when the operation is "not supported"?

Tags: c#, datetime, converters

The [`Convert.ToInt32(DateTime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch56d3w9(v=vs.110).aspx) method is documented to always throw an `InvalidCastException` because "This conversion is not supported."

If its not supported, why does it even exist? Wouldn't it make more sense to just not have that function?

Comment: This question isn't really answerable (unless a member of the BCL team deigns to enlighten us all). Otherwise it's really just opinion about the design of an API.

Comment: FWIW, DateTime is IConvertible and there is IConvertible.ToInt32. I imagine that is where the "source" of the issue comes from. This actually makes it more consistent such that `Converter.ToInt32((object)dt)`, where the object is treated as an IConvertible, will yield the same exception.

Comment: ILSpy shows this: `public static int ToInt32(DateTime value)
{ return ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(null); }`

Comment: All of the `IConvertible` methods implemented by `DateTime` appear to throw an exception (except for the `ToDateTime` method). The `IConvertible` implementations of `Int32` and `Int64`, at least, also appear to throw an exception for `IConvertible.ToDateTime`. So a related question might be "why does DateTime implement IConvertible, when it won't convert to anything, and nothing will convert to it?"

Comment: @pmcoltrane `string` will convert to `DateTime` and vice versa, so not "nothing" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [`Convert`](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Convert@cs/1/Convert@cs) implementation you can see that it relies on the [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface being implemented by the types that are being converted. The `IConvertible` interface forces a type to implement **all** conversion methods, and it is intended to work as you've described:

> If there is no meaningful conversion to a common language runtime type, then a particular interface method implementation throws `InvalidCastException`.

So the method in question exists in `Convert` class *probably* because all `IConvertible`s have to have this method:

```
public static int ToInt32(DateTime value)
{
    return ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(null);
}
```

So, similar to what others have noted seems that it's a matter of consistency with `IConvertible` interface and completeness. The `Convert`'s implementation might even be generated, as it only relies on `IConvertible`.

Comment: Agree with this - consistency due to IConvertible. Also MSDN states that some conversions would fail depending on the magnitude of the input (i.e. large double to a single) - allowing the exceptions means they don't have to do loads of boundary checking etc.

Answer (score 3):

My previous hunch on code generation was wrong. It's actually a lot simpler than that: almost all implementations of the `IConvertible` interface in [`DateTime`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1400) throw a `InvalidCastException`. These calls are always invoked when you call `Convert.ToXXX()` as you can see here:

[`Convert.ToInt64`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs#1332):

```
public static long ToInt64(DateTime value)
{
    return ((IConvertible)value).ToInt64(null);
}
```

Bottom line? Microsoft wanted to implement the `IConvertible` interface in `DateTime` but did not want to provide implementations for any conversion other than [`ToDateTime`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1438), [`ToString`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1219) and [`ToType`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/iconvertible.cs#68).

Comment: I don't agree with the "generated" portion (it's not really that hard to change such a template if one is used; although it might fall into the realm of That is Just How It Is), but it does make sense that the issue is related to IConvertible.

Comment: @user2864740: I'm not entirely sure anymore about the generated code either because [`DateTime` explicitly defines all conversions as a `ClassCastException`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1400), even `ToInt64` which supposedly works.

Comment: I don't think `ToInt64` does work: It's documented as not working, and decompiling with ILSpy agrees.

Comment: Don't forget `ToString(IFormatProvider)` :)

Comment: @dlev: ah, sneaky one! It's the only implementation that didn't have the interface explicitly named in it.